# Google CalDAV API 403 error when I want to write on the primary calendar (read is ok)

Tags: calendar, google-api, http-status-code-403, caldav

My problem: I use Google's CalDAV APIs to read and write on the Google calendar. It works fine on all calendars **but** the user's primary calendar. Reading works fine on the user's primary calendar (calendar id is the same as that user's email address), but when I try to write (with a PUT request) I get an HTTP error response with status 403 (need-privileges)

I use scope calendar, task an cardav;

Thanks for you help

Damien

Comment: What does "I use scope calendar, task an cardav" mean?

Comment: @hnh he probably means the scopes he used to acquire an OAuth2 access token.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I found the problem : when I recovered the calendar with the " PROFIND " function, the first returned agenda was the holidays calendar, which is not editable. This problem was not met when I interviewed a secondary calendar because the ID is specific, and so i recovered the good calendar.